# Particular solution of the second order non homogeneous equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation as follows:

$$y''-4y'-4sy=\frac{4}{s} \mathrm{exp}(2x-2x\sqrt{1+s})$$

The general solution of the above equation would be in the form of

$$y = C_1 \exp{[(2+2\sqrt{1+s})x]}+C_2\, \exp{[(2-2\sqrt{1+s})x]}$$

I would appreciate any suggestions on solving for the particular solution.

Where s can be treated as a constant positive number. 
Thank you.

Comment: Method of undetermined coefficients. Look for $Dxe^{ax}$ with $a=2-2\sqrt{1+s}$. Note your homogeneous solution has a typo. You miss an $x$ after each first $2$ in the exponent.

Comment: @julien Yes, you are correct. I am missing x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the RHS is already a solution to the differential equation.  One way to deal with this is to use

$$y_p = A x \exp{[(2-\sqrt{1+s}) x]}$$

as a particular solution.  When you plug into the diff eq'n, you get

$$A [2 (2-\sqrt{1+s}) - 4] = \frac{4}{s} \implies A = -\frac{1}{s \sqrt{1+s}}$$

Comment: Given the rhs, woudn't it be better to have a $+$ instead of the first  $-$ in the exponent?

Comment: @julien: yep, it would.

Comment: @RonGordon When you assume yp , is it yp = A * exp(...) or yp = Ax exp(...). I think that should be a multiplier sign. What do you think ?

Comment: @Jdbaba: no, it is the variable $x$.  Note that this symbol is also used inside the exponential, so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @ Ron If you look at the solution from Wolfram http://bit.ly/XqjYWs , the solution you provided is different from the solution given there. Would you please check this link ?

Comment: @Jdbaba: thanks for the catch; the equation on the left was correct, but the final expression had an error.

Comment: @RonGordon I still don't understand your solution. To use the yp in the differential equation you need to find y' and y'' and I am not sure the expressions you put there are correct or not.

Comment: @Jdbaba: That's right: you have to find $y_p'$ and $y_p''$ to solve for $A$. The expressions are correct.  I am not sure what you do not understand.  The idea is that, because the RHS satisfies the equation, the particular solution cannot take that form.  In cases where the RHS is an exponential, it is a known technique to use a linear term times the exponential as the particular solution, which I did.

Comment: @ Ron: Finally, figured it out. Thanks.